# $28$ th largest known prime missing in the prime page database?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

If I here

https://primes.utm.edu/primes/search.php

enter $30$ at the last field, I should get the $30$ largest known primes. Apparently, the $28$ th largest known prime is missing. Is this an error in the database , or do I miss something ?

Comment: Another downvote without a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a glitch in the way the primes are pulled out of the database. Download the list of the top 5000. You get:

$26:  3*2^{11484018}-1$

$27:  193997*2^{11452891}+1$

$28: 2877652^{524288}+1$

$29: 2788032^{524288}+1$

$30:  2733014^{524288}+1$

Same primes, but now correctly labelled.